# Are abstract methods virtual?

Tags: c#

Am I correct that declaring a method `abstract` automatically makes it virtual?

That is, in subclasses I can override it many times and at runtime, the method corresponding to the runtime type of the object will be called?

Is it possible to declare an abstract non-virtual method? That is, the method which must be implemented in a non-abstract subclass and can not be overridden?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is every abstract function virtual in C#, in general?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391557/is-every-abstract-function-virtual-in-c-in-general)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, [abstract methods are virtual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664435.aspx) by definition; they must be overridable in order to actually be overridden by subclasses:

> When an instance method declaration includes an `abstract` modifier, that method is said to be an abstract method. Although **an abstract method is implicitly also a virtual method**, it cannot have the modifier `virtual`.

Conversely you can't declare an abstract non-virtual method, because if you could, you would have a method that can't be implemented and thus can never be called, making it rather useless.

However, if you want to have a class implement an abstract method but not allow any of its subclasses to modify its implementation, that's where [`sealed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645769.aspx) comes in. An example:

```
abstract public class AbstractClass
{
    abstract public void DoSomething();
}

public class BaseClass : AbstractClass
{
    public sealed override void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Did something");
    }
}
```

Notice that while the abstract method is (implicitly) virtual, the implementation in the concrete base class is non-virtual (because of the `sealed` keyword).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are virtual. Otherwise you would have no way to write implementation for them.