# Can we change grand parent class's method definitions?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

I was working on a certain problem and found some interesting problem inside.

Let me explain with an example (C# code)

```
public class A: IA
{
    protected abstract void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    { 
          //Some definition
    }
}


public class B: A
{
    protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    { 
          //override definition
    }
}



public class MyClass: B
{
    //Here I want to change the definition of Append method.
}
```

Class A and B are of a certain library and I don't have any control to change those classes.

Comment: You can override again. Very simple to try and verify.

Comment: @HimBromBeere - Append() _remains_ virtual until you seal it.

Comment: Note that Append() in A cannot have code in it like your example. It's either an abstract method without an implementation or you can declare it as virtual if you want to put something there.

Answer (score 1):

Since none of the methods in the hierarchy here are `sealed`, you can just continue overriding the method yourself:

```
public class MyClass: B
{
    protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    { 
          // New logic goes here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have shared the solution below based as per my research, but made few following changes to the code you shared based on my perception, since the code in the question is not valid at few occasions.

1. Added an empty Interface IA, as Class A is not implementing any **public** method.
2. Defined Class A as abstract, as any **non-abstract class** cannot define a abstract method.
3. Removed the body for Append method inside Class A, as a abstract method **cannot** have a body.

   ```
   public interface IA
   {

   }

   public abstract class A : IA
   {
       protected abstract void Append();

   }

   public class B : A
   {
       protected override void Append()
       {
           //override definition
       }
   }

   public class MyClass : B
   {
       //Here I want to change the definition of Append method.

       //You can do is hide the method by creating a new method with the same name
       public new void Append() { }
   }
   ```

**Answer :** You cannot override a non-virtual method. The closest thing you can do is hide the method by creating a new method with the same name but this is not advisable as it breaks good design principles.
But even hiding a method won't give you execution time polymorphic dispatch of method calls like a true virtual method call would.

Comment: [Abstract methods are implicitly virtual.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391557/is-every-abstract-function-virtual-in-c-in-general)  Method hiding is exactly what OP does *not* want to do.

Comment: @BJMyers I agree with you completely. The question itself is not very much pinpoint. The above answer comes with possible corrections to the question and at the end of the Answer, I do highlight that Method Hiding is not recommended. Thanks for your help :)