# When would you use Abstract methods over virtual methods in C#?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between an abstract and virtual function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391483/what-is-the-difference-between-abstract-function-and-virtual-function)

What are the advantages of using `abstract` over `virtual` methods and vice versa?

**Abstract Methods:**

- Only the abstract class can hold abstract methods.
- Also the derived class need to implement the method and no implmentation is provided in the class.

**Virtual Methods:**

- A class can declare these and also provide the implementaion of the same.
- Also the derived class need to implement of the method to override it.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391483/what-is-the-difference-between-abstract-function-and-virtual-function