# cannot declare a body because it is marked abstract

Tags: c#

Hi i'm new in C# console application and i'm using abstract and override but i get stack in the first method in **public abstract double Compute()** i got an error and it says **cannot declare a body because it is marked abstract** please help me. thank you!

`

```
abstract class Cake
    {
        public string _flavor, _size;
        public int _quantity;

        public Cake(string flavor, string size, int quantity)
        {
            _flavor = flavor;
            _size = size;
            _quantity = quantity;
        }

        public abstract double Compute()
        {
            double price;
            if(_flavor == "Chocolate" && _size == "Regular")
            {
               price = 250.50;
            }
            else if (_flavor == "Chocolate" && _size == "Large")
            {
                price = 450.50;
            }
            else if (_flavor == "Strawberry" && _size == "Regular")
            {
                price = 300.50;
            }
            else
            {
                price = 500.75;
            }
            return price;
        }
    }

    class BirthdayCake:Cake
    {
        public int _numOfCandles;

        public BirthdayCake(string flavor, string size, int quantity, int numOfCandles):base(flavor,size,quantity)
        {
            _numOfCandles = numOfCandles;
        }

        public override double Compute()
        {
            return _numOfCandles * 10.00;
        }
    }`
```

Comment: Use *virtual* instead of *abstract* when you have a default implementation but would like to allow sub-classes to override.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14728761/difference-between-virtual-and-abstract-methods

Comment: If you declare an abstract function in an abstract class,.You should not declare body in the same class. It must implement its derived class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use ***virtual*** instead of ***abstract*** when you have a default implementation but would like to allow sub-classes to override

Answer (score 3):

As said, you can't declare a body for an `abstract function` of an `abstract class`.

You need to create another class herited from your `abstract class` that declare the body you want.

```
abstract class Cake
{
    public string _flavor, _size;
    public int _quantity;
    abstract public double Compute();
}

class BirthdayCake : Cake
{
    public int _numOfCandles;


    public BirthdayCake(string flavor, string size, int quantity, int numOfCandles):base(flavor,size,quantity)
    {
        _numOfCandles = numOfCandles;
    }

    public override double Compute()
    {
        //does your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on the example it's much more likely the OP actually wants to use virtual instead of abstract.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Edited.

Answer (score 2):

**abstract class** is a class in which you can have functions which are **abstract**.

**abstract function** is a function inside an **abstract class** that has no body and also it forces you to **override** it in the derived class.

Your issue here is that you wrote an **abstract function** that has a body.

***Fix:*** Use **virtual** keyword instead of **abstract**. **virtual** don't force you to override the function and you can also have a body in your base class.
 (NB: If you are using **virtual function** instead of **abstract function** remove the **abstract** keyword from your class too.)

Comment: Abhimanue Sanjay . It is not mandatory for an abstract class to have at least one function which is abstract.

Comment: An abstarct class can be empty.

Comment: SunilDhappadhule, Thank you. I wasn't sure about that. But what is the use of an empty abstract class?

Comment: Abhimanue Sanjay, No Use, An empty abstract class is very much equivalent to an interface except that it can extend a class

Answer (score 1):

Abstract methods have no implementation in the same class, so the method definition is followed by a semicolon instead of a normal method block. Derived classes of the abstract class must implement all abstract methods. When an abstract class inherits a virtual method from a base class, the abstract class can override the virtual method with an abstract method. e.g:

> Abstract methods have no implementation in the same class-Sample code

```
public abstract class A
{
public abstract void DoWork(int i);
public String DoWork(String str)
{
  return str;
}

}
public class B:A
{
    public virtual void DoWork(int i)
    {
        // here implementation.
    }
}
```