# C# inherited classes of an abstract class with cast Type

Tags: c#, overriding, inherited

I have two abstract classes:

```
abstract class Item
{
    public string name { get; set; };
    public abstract Genre Genre { get; set; };
}

abstract class Genre
{
    public string name { get; set; };
}
```

And their children:

```
class weapon : Item
{
    public virtual GenreWeapon Genre { get; set; };
}

class armor : Item
{
    public virtual GenreArmor Genre { get; set; };
}

class GenreWeapon : Genre
{
    public int Damage { get; set; };
}

class GenreArmor : Genre
{
    public int DamageReduction { get; set; };
}
```

But I don't know how to do it, I try with

```
public new virtual GenreWeapon Genre { get; set; };
```

but if I have `Item.Genre`, I get NULL

I try override but VS say it's impossible because its not the same class.

I try a lot of thing but don't know how to do it

Please help me I became crazy.

Thanks

A small example:

a shop contain a lot of items, and the price of a item depend on Genre and Quality

So in the Shop I have something like

```
List<Item> listItem = new List<Item>();

foreach (Item i in listItem)
{
    int prix = i.Genre.Prix;
    String Quality = i.Quality;

    if (i is Weapon arme)
    {
        int dégats = arme.Genre.Dégats;
    }

    if (i is armor armor)
    {
        int resist = armor.Genre.Armor;
    }
}
```

It's just a quick example, maybe not good ^^

I want everywhere without cast get the damage of a weapon, and the price of all items, and to create a weapon I just have to do:

```
GenreWeapon sword = (get the GenreWeapon i need);

Weapon w = new Weapon{Genre = sword, name = "old sword of your granny" , quality = "bad"};
```

But I don't now how deal with Genre in Item and int Weapon without casting everywhere in the code

Comment: Looks like `Item` should be generic `Item<T> where T : Genre`  and then you can do `Weapon : Item<GenreWeapon>`

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to access `Genre` on an instance of `Item`? I think you need an [mre] showing how you plan to use these classes. [edit] your answer.

Comment: Don't overload Genre. Assign a new object of a derivative to the property. Also don't reuse names. Both the property type and name the same is asking for problems

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you want to achieve by implementing abstract classes.
First, take a look at what makes the difference between a virtual class and an abstract class.
[Difference between virtual and abstract methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14728761/difference-between-virtual-and-abstract-methods)

Additionally, have a look at the code that shows how you can use the code.

```
    public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    }
    public class Genre
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Weapon : Item
    {
      // No code needed because everything is inherited from Item
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Genre Axe = new Genre() { Name = "Axe" };
        Weapon weapon = new Weapon() { Genre = Axe };
        Console.WriteLine(weapon.Genre.Name);

    }
```

If you give more information on why you need an abstract class, I will probably be able to help

Comment: i use virtual because i need it for my BDD on .NetCore