# Is there a way to raise an error at compile-time if I don't override the virtual method?

Tags: c#, overriding, decorator

Please note in advance that this is a code written for **learning purposes**. Please look at the **flow** rather than the direct implementation :D

---

I have a `FileHandler` that simply reads and writes files.

```cs
public class FileHandler : IReadAndWriteHandler
{
    private const string Path = @"C:\Temp\tempFile.txt";
    
    public void Write(string message)
    {
        using var writer = new StreamWriter(Path);
        writer.WriteLine(message);
    }

    public string Read()
    {
        using var reader = new StreamReader(Path);
        
        return  reader.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

```cs
public interface IReadAndWriteHandler
{
    public void Write(string message);
    public string Read();
}
```

To extend the functionality, we decide to use the **Decorator pattern**. So, I wrote a decorator like this:

```cs
public abstract class HandlerDecorator : IReadAndWriteHandler
{
    private readonly IReadAndWriteHandler _handler;

    protected HandlerDecorator(IReadAndWriteHandler handler)
    {
        _handler = handler;
    }
    
    public virtual void Write(string message)
    {
        _handler.Write(message);
    }

    public virtual string Read()
    {
        return _handler.Read();
    }
}
```

Now we can extend our functionality by inheritance our decorator. I wrote an `EncryptionHandlerDecorator` that does encryption. But I accidentally forgot to override `Read()`.

```cs
public class EncryptionHandlerDecorator : HandlerDecorator
{
    public EncryptionHandlerDecorator(IReadAndWriteHandler handler)
        : base(handler)
    {
        
    }

    public override void Write(string message)
    {
        base.Write(Encrypt(message));
    }

    private static string Encrypt(string message) => $"Encrpyt({message})";
}
```

However, It doesn't raise an error at compile-time, so it works fine. Very sadly, when you actually use it, the encrypted content is read, so it's wrong code.

To solve this, there is a way to directly implement one by one without using an abstract class, but that is not the point of this question right now.

If I don't override a virtual method defined in an abstract class, is there a way to raise an error at compile-time like an interface?

Comment: This largely depends on your IDE. I believe in most you can redefine how the IDE reacts to a certain "trigger". And most have a trigger on this, because many, if not all IDE's mark the virtual keyword as "grey", if you do not have an overload. However. I am not certain about this. I would take a look at your IDE's online documentation.

Comment: Why don't you made the method abstract?

Comment: @MortenBork I'm currently using **Rider**, so I'll ask **JetBrains** as you say. Thanks for the good info :D

Comment: @Turo I don't understand, can you explain a little bit longer?

Comment: Why didn't you just define the method in the abstract class?:
`public abstract string Read();`

Comment: @Turo Wow! Why didn't I just think of creating an abstract method? Thanks to your insight, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for [abstract methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14729005/8031115), which **requires** derived classes to implement the function. However, you'll need to define `internal` scoped functions, so derived classes can write to the handler itself, as the base implementation will no longer be available to it.

```cs
public abstract class HandlerDecorator : IReadAndWriteHandler
{
    private readonly IReadAndWriteHandler _handler;

    protected HandlerDecorator(IReadAndWriteHandler handler)
    {
        _handler = handler;
    }
    
    public abstract void Write(string message);

    public abstract string Read();

    internal void WriteRaw(string message)
    {
        _handler.Write(message);
    }

    internal string ReadRaw()
    {
        return _handler.Read();
    }
}
```