# Confused with override and new functionality C#

Tags: c#, .net, oop, .net-4.5

While going through the differences between Abstract and virtual methods at [Difference between Abstract and Virtual Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391483/what-is-the-difference-between-an-abstract-function-and-a-virtual-function).

I got a doubt related to `virtual` and `new`

Let's consider a sample code as below

```
 class MainClass
 {
   public static void Main()
   {         
       DerivedClass _derived = new DerivedClass();          
       _derived.SayHello();          
       _derived.SayGoodbye();
       Console.ReadLine();
   }      
 }

public abstract class AbstractClass
{
   public void SayHello()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Hello - abstract member\n");
   }

   public virtual void SayGoodbye()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Goodbye- abstract member \n");
   }
   //public abstract void SayGoodbye();
}


public class DerivedClass : AbstractClass
{
   public new void SayHello()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Hi There - Hiding base class member");
   }

   //public override void SayGoodbye()
   //{
   //    Console.WriteLine("See you later - In derived class OVERRIDE function");
   //}

   public new void SayGoodbye()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("See you later - In derived class I'm in  NEW  member");
   }           
}
```

**My Question:**
In the derived class, How `override` and `new` perform the same functionality if i call `SayGoodbye` function? When i need to go to choose/ prefer among them? In which real time scenarios i need to prefer among them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392721/difference-between-shadowing-and-overriding-in-c

Comment: The question/answer @Oded links to perfectly answers your question.

Comment: Just try this with your above code: `Console.WriteLine((AbstractClass)_derived.SayGoodbye());`. It will execute the base class method. That would not happen if you had overridden instead of hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- When you mark a class member as `virtual` it can be overrided in the sub classes.
- If you want to change a method (which was declared virtual in base class) in sub class you can use both `new` and `override` keywords but there is a difference between them

  . **When using new**: if you cast an object of sub class as base class, then call that method, base class implementation will run

  . **When using override**: if you cast an object of sub class as base class, then call that method, sub class implementation will run.

Here is the code

```
AbstractClass instance = new DerivedClass();
instance.SayGoodbye();  //See you later - In derived class I'm in  NEW  member
```

But if you use `override`

```
AbstractClass instance = new DerivedClass();
instance.SayGoodbye();  //Goodbye- abstract member \n
```

Comment: If you don't cast an object of sub class as base class? then will it be makes any difference?

Comment: @sukumar Not sure about the answer in this case, you may search for it or ask it as a different question.