# Overriding an abstract method with a virtual one

Tags: c#, inheritance, virtual, abstract

I'm trying to override an abstract method in an abstract class with a virtual method in a child class. I (assumed until now?) understand the difference between abstract and virtual methods.

Obviously I'm not able to do it but my question is... why? Based on the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391483/what-is-the-difference-between-an-abstract-function-and-a-virtual-function) and the following scenario, I just don't see the problem:

```
    public abstract class TopLevelParent
    {
        protected abstract void TheAbstractMethod();
    }

    public class FirstLevelChild1 : TopLevelParent
    {
        protected override void TheAbstractMethod()
        {

        }
    }

    public class FirstLevelChild2 : TopLevelParent
    {
        protected virtual override void TheAbstractMethod()
        {
            //Do some stuff here
        }
    }

    public class SecondLevelChild : FirstLevelChild2
    {
        //Don't need to re-implement the method here... my parent does it the way I need.
    }
```

So obviosuly what I've done is have a top-level parent with two inheriting children and another class inheriting from one of those. Again, based on the accepted answer in the link I posted above:

> "A virtual function, is basically saying look, here's the functionality
>   that may or may not be good enough for the child class. So if it is
>   good enough, use this method, if not, then override me, and provide
>   your own functionality."

and that the second level child will inherit the virtual method from its parent, thus satisfying the implementation requirement of the abstract method from its top-most parent... what's the problem?

I'm missing some detail somewhere that's hindering my understanding of this...

Comment: What exactly is the error you're getting?

Comment: A member 'WindowsFormsApplication.Form1.FirstLevelChild2.TheAbstractMethod()" marked as override cannot be marked as new or virtual

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An [`override`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx) method *is* implicitly virtual (in the sense that it can be overridden in a subclass), unless marked as [`sealed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx).

Observe:

```
public class FirstLevelChild1 : TopLevelParent
{
    protected override void TheAbstractMethod() { }
}

public class SecondLevelChild1 : FirstLevelChild1
{
    protected override void TheAbstractMethod() { } // No problem
}

public class FirstLevelChild2 : TopLevelParent
{
    protected sealed override void TheAbstractMethod() { }
}

public class SecondLevelChild : FirstLevelChild2
{
    protected override void TheAbstractMethod() { } 
    // Error: cannot override inherited member 
    // 'FirstLevelChild2.TheAbstractMethod()' because it is sealed
}
```

Comment: Ah yes... I see now. So in this case my virtual declaration is essentially redundant? I was able to just declare it as override and it worked as I expected.

Comment: +1 I didn't know that we can mark methods as sealed :)

Answer (score 4):

An `abstract` method is *already* `virtual` all the way down the inheritance chain - there's no need to declare it `virtual` in a subclass to allow the subclass to override it - the subclass can *already* override it.

If you *don't* provide an implementation, the closest implementation (looking down the inheritance list) will be used.