# Why is the Up() method abstract and the Down() method virtual in the DbMigration class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

If you look at the signature of the abstract class `DBMigration` in the `System.Data.Entity.Migrations` namespace:

```
public virtual void Down();
public abstract void Up();
```

You'll see that `Down()` is marked `virtual` and `Up` is marked `abstract`. The difference between virtual and abstract is that an abstract function [can have functionality in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391483/what-is-the-difference-between-an-abstract-function-and-a-virtual-function).

What kind of functionality can the `Up()` function have default and why isn't it the case with th `Down()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override `Up()` while overriding `Down()` is optional. This makes sense for database migration instructions.

See also [What is the difference between an abstract function and a virtual function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/391492/344480).