# make abstract a method with body for overriding

Tags: c#, oop, overriding, decorator, abstract

I have my *Beverage* class, which has some getters/setters to work with the size of the beverage. This program has to do with the decorator pattern, so I want to combine the behavior of some methods equally named.

My intent is to have a method with body that allows me to get the size of the beverage, but then, I want to be able to override that behavior on child classes.

In sum, I want a method that:

- if not overriden, just behaves as the method in the parent class
- if overriden, behaves like it is coded

What I did was to create a method called *getSizeOfBeverage* that behaves like my "old" *getSize* did, and made the *getSize* "new" method abstract so I can override it, but I want a solution that does not imply a new method name.

Here is my code:

```
using System;

namespace Decorator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Beverage beverage = new Espresso("small");
            beverage = new Whip(beverage);
            Console.WriteLine(beverage.getDescription() + " $" + beverage.cost());
        }
    }

    abstract class Beverage
    {
      private string description;
      private string size;

      public Beverage()
      {
        setDescription("Unknown beverage");
      }

      public double getCost()
      {
        return cost();
      }

      public abstract double cost();

      public abstract string getDescription();

      public void setDescription(string desc)
      {
        description = desc;
      }

      public string getSizeOfBeverage()
      {
        return size;
      }

      public abstract string getSize();

      public void setSize(string sz)
      {
        size = sz;
      }
    }

    class Espresso : Beverage
    {
      public Espresso(string sz)
      {
        setSize(sz);
        setDescription("Espresso");
      }

      public override double cost()
      {
        return 1.9;
      }

      public override string getDescription()
      {
        return getDescription();
      }

      public override string getSize()
      {
        return getSizeOfBeverage();
      }
    }

    abstract class CondimentDecorator : Beverage
    {
      public abstract override string getSize();
    }

    class Whip : CondimentDecorator
    {
      private Beverage beverage;

      public Whip(Beverage bv)
      {
        beverage = bv;
      }

      public override double cost()
      {
        if (getSize() == "small")
        {
          return 0.1 + beverage.cost();
        }
        else if (getSize() == "medium")
        {
          return 0.15 + beverage.cost();
        }
        else
        {
          return 0.2 + beverage.cost();
        }
      }

      public override string getDescription()
      {
        return beverage.getDescription() + ", whip";
      }

      public override string getSize()
      {
        return beverage.getSizeOfBeverage();
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> if not overriden, just behaves as the method in the parent class if
>
> overriden, behaves like it is coded

Every `virtual` method works like this:

If it is overriden it will behave like it is coded, if not just behaves as the method in the parent class

From the documentation for [virtual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx)

> The virtual keyword is used to modify a method, property, indexer, or
> event declaration and allow for it to be overridden in a derived
> class. For example, this method can be overridden by any class that
> inherits it:

and [abstract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664435(v=vs.71).aspx)

> When an instance method declaration includes an abstract modifier,
> that method is said to be an abstract method. Although an abstract
> method is implicitly also a virtual method, it cannot have the
> modifier virtual. An abstract method declaration introduces a new
> virtual method but does not provide an implementation of that method.
> Instead, non-abstract derived classes are required to provide their
> own implementation by overriding that method. Because an abstract
> method provides no actual implementation, the method-body of an
> abstract method simply consists of a semicolon.

See the difference between [virtual and abstract methods in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391483/what-is-the-difference-between-an-abstract-function-and-a-virtual-function)